# How to set ORM Two Entity id's in Symfony

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, orm

Here i'm new to symfony, i tried to set two id's as orm entity its taken first coloumn as primarykey but second coloumn doesn't present in database, can any one help me to solve this problem.

My ORM Entity

```
id:
    merchantId:
      type: merchant_id
      column: merchant_id
    auto_id:
        type: integer
        auto_id: true
        column: auto_id
        associationKey: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
```

merchantId is my uuid(PostgreSQL DB),
  auto_id is auto increment id (1,2,3....).

How to i solve this, can any one help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

When I mapped the entity it looks like this

```
   SomeBundle\Entity\Example:
    type: entity
    table: example
    id:
        firstId:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            column: first_id
        secondId:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: null
            options:
                fixed: false
            id: true
            column: second_id
    fields:
        someExtraData:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            options:
                fixed: false
            column: some_extra_data
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

You could try either way desing the entity and mappit or update your entity declaration.